404 Not Found ID: cpt1::r4ljq-1721260694133-e0487a97aa5c
I am getting a 404 not found on when trying to trying to hit the domain for an api I am trying to connect to. Im new to dev so Im sure there is something silly I am doing.
The app is on node.js and am I am using Vercel. I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you in advance.
Vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "server.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ]
  }

server.js
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const lastFmUsername = 'xxxx';
const apiKey = 'xxxxx';

app.get('/api/song', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=${lastFmUsername}&api_key=${apiKey}&format=json`);
        const data = await response.json();
        const tracks = data.recenttracks.track;
        if (tracks.length > 0) {
            const nowPlaying = tracks[0];
            const trackName = nowPlaying.name;
            const artistName = nowPlaying.artist['#text'];
            const spotifyUrl = `https://open.spotify.com/search/${encodeURIComponent(trackName + ' ' + artistName)}`;

            res.send(`Currently playing: ${trackName} - ${artistName} [${spotifyUrl}]`);
        } else {
            res.send('No track playing');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.send('Error fetching song data');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);

package.json
{
    "name": "lastfmcatcherv2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "A Node.js server to fetch and display current song information from Last.fm.",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.18.2",
      "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
      "cors": "^2.8.5"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": "18.x"
    }
  }

